# Creating description input field with punctuation support

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to find the best way to make a text editor like the one I'm currently typing into that has bold, Italics, underline, etc... like in pic below

[image]

I haven't been able to find a library in npmjs, but maybe I'm not using the correct verbage in my search. Is there a library that provides such a solution or do I need to make it from scratch?

Comment: There's plenty of options, for example https://ckeditor.com/.

Comment: If you can effort license version . Primeng and ag grid are also good option

Comment: Ok cool! When I was searching npmjs I didn't use the keyword ```editor```. That made a big difference in my search. I see options in npmjs now. Thanks!